# Querying tags with Cosmos DB with EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a domain model that is persisted with EF Core and the Cosmos DB provider. The problem is, I would like to add to it tags, which I would like to query, e.g., return all entries that have this tag. Unfortunately, Cosmos DB does not support string arrays (among others), so I can only imagine using a single string property, which is far from ideal, because if I need multiple tags I would need to combine them on the same property, probably separated by spaces, and this would make querying of a single one very difficult. What are the best options for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a POCO:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then your model class looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Instruct EF how to handle the model either by overriding OnModelCreating() or using separate config files:

```
// Configure the one-to-many/owns many relationship:
builder
   .OwnsMany(
      ownedType: typeof(Tag),
      navigationName: nameof(MyEntity.Tags))
   .WithOwner();
```

This will produce something like the following:

```
{
    "Id": "some-unique-id",
    "Name": "The name of the entity",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Name": "Developer"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Hacker"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Guru"
        } 
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a simple conversion like this:

```
builder.Property(c => c.Tags)
    .HasConversion(
        v => string.Join(',', v),
        v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    );
```

Which would allow querying against the list of strings as desired, but gets persisted as a comma-delimited string value in the database.  While this could be okay, you would lose some querying ability within Cosmos Db.

*Note: you may also need to implement a comparer in order for EF to track changes properly.*

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of EF Core, not Cosmos DB - to disallow entities with properties of string arrays.
To go around this, I just used the Cosmos DB API and dropped EF Core.